# Angular Material components not recognized by VSCode (highlighted be red color)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-material

I'm using Visual Studio Code when developing an Angular v6 project (based on [this](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter) starter), which includes the Angular Material module.

The project compiles and runs well, but in the editor, Angular Material components are not recognized:

[image: Unrecognized components]

I guess the problem of recognition is because material module not imported to the module directly, but imports "shared" module which imports material, but maybe I'm missing something .

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Did you import `MatIconModule` in your app's main module/material module?

`material.module.ts`

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatIconModule
    // ...
  ],
  exports: [
    MatIconModule
    // ...
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

`app.module.ts`

```ts
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
// Other imports

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule
    // ...
  ]
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Alternatively (assuming you don't have a material module):

`app.module.ts`

```ts
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
// Other imports

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatIconModule
    // ...
  ]
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the JS Module

```
import { MaterialIconsModule } from 'ionic2-material-icons';
```

Import it in angular imports

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [MyApp],
  imports: [
    MaterialIconsModule
  ],
```

Some times VSCode needs a restart to recognize such changes.

Comment: the materialIconModule included in project (although not in this module directly)